# Why PHP json_decode can't parse this JSON

Tags: php, json, parsing, request

I have a cURL request to a server and it returns this jsonp type of data but I don't know why PHP `json_decode` return nothing when parsing this JSON text.
This is what I get for the request:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Color Collections",
    "category": "collection",
    "palettes": [
      {
        "name": "America's Colors",
        "category": "collection",
        "colors": [
          {
            "number": "AC-1",
            "name": "Coastal Fog",
            "family": "Neutral",
            "url": "http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/paint-color/ac-1?apiKey=9471009bd36bd062c688",
            "shortURL": "/ac-1",
            "hex": "CAC4B0",
            "r": 202,
            "g": 196,
            "b": 176,
            "exteriorAvailability": "available",
            "wetSampleSKU": null,
            "drySampleSKU": null,
            "eStoreAvailable": false,
            "productTypesAvailable": "paint",
            "stainOpacitiesAvailable": null
          },
          
        ],
        "colorList": [
          "AC-1",
          "AC-2",
          "AC-3",
          "AC-4",
          "AC-5",
          "AC-6",
          "AC-7",
          "AC-8",
          "AC-9",
          "AC-10",
          "AC-11",
          "AC-12",
          "AC-13",
          "AC-14",
          "AC-15",
          "AC-16",
          "AC-17",
          "AC-18",
          "AC-19",
          "AC-20",
          "AC-21",
          "AC-22",
          "AC-23",
          "AC-24",
          "AC-25",
          "AC-26",
          "AC-27",
          "AC-28",
          "AC-29",
          "AC-30",
          "AC-31",
          "AC-32",
          "AC-33",
          "AC-34",
          "AC-35",
          "AC-36",
          "AC-37",
          "AC-38",
          "AC-39",
          "AC-40",
          "AC-41",
          "AC-42"
        ],
        "code": "AC",
        "description": "42 soft hues inspired by the pale gray of our beautiful coastlines to the rich earth tones of our Southwestern deserts. ",
        "url": "http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/for-your-home/color-gallery?apiKey=9471009bd36bd062c688#&ce_vm=2&ce_col=AC?apiKey=9471009bd36bd062c688",
        "rows": 7,
        "totalColors": 42,
        "eStoreProductCode": null
      },
    ]
  },
  "error": "",
  "countryCode": "en-us",
  "brand": "BenjaminMoore,Corotech,Coronado,Inslx,Lenmar,Maxum"
}
```

But even I removed some parts to make it working like so short but still nothing returns from PHP `json_decode`. this is my code look and tell me what is happening here? Why PHP can't parse this?

```php
 $jsonData = '{
    "data": {
      "name": "Color Collections",
      "category": "collection",
    },
    "error": "",
    "countryCode": "en-us",
    "brand": "BenjaminMoore,Corotech,Coronado,Inslx,Lenmar,Maxum"
  }';
  print_r( json_decode($jsonData, true));
```

Comment: first escape the single quote "name": "America's Colors" **** second remove the extra comma in the closing curly braces. "stainOpacitiesAvailable": null
          }, and "eStoreProductCode": null
      },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these are valid JSON. You can always run your JSON through a lint like [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com) to make sure it's valid.

Your smaller example has an extra comma on line 4:

```
  {
    "data": {
      "name": "Color Collections",
      "category": "collection", //<-------------here
    },
    "error": "",
    "countryCode": "en-us",
    "brand": "BenjaminMoore,Corotech,Coronado,Inslx,Lenmar,Maxum"
  }
```

And your larger one has an extra comma on line 24.

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Color Collections",
    "category": "collection",
    "palettes": [
      {
        "name": "America's Colors",
        "category": "collection",
        "colors": [
          {
            "number": "AC-1",
            "name": "Coastal Fog",
            "family": "Neutral",
            "url": "http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/paint-color/ac-1?apiKey=9471009bd36bd062c688",
            "shortURL": "/ac-1",
            "hex": "CAC4B0",
            "r": 202,
            "g": 196,
            "b": 176,
            "exteriorAvailability": "available",
            "wetSampleSKU": null,
            "drySampleSKU": null,
            "eStoreAvailable": false,
            "productTypesAvailable": "paint",
            "stainOpacitiesAvailable": null
          }, //<------------------------------------- here
          
        ],
        "colorList": [
          "AC-1",
          "AC-2",
          "AC-3",
          "AC-4",
          "AC-5",
          "AC-6",
          "AC-7",
          "AC-8",
          "AC-9",
          "AC-10",
          "AC-11",
          "AC-12",
          "AC-13",
          "AC-14",
          "AC-15",
          "AC-16",
          "AC-17",
          "AC-18",
          "AC-19",
          "AC-20",
          "AC-21",
          "AC-22",
          "AC-23",
          "AC-24",
          "AC-25",
          "AC-26",
          "AC-27",
          "AC-28",
          "AC-29",
          "AC-30",
          "AC-31",
          "AC-32",
          "AC-33",
          "AC-34",
          "AC-35",
          "AC-36",
          "AC-37",
          "AC-38",
          "AC-39",
          "AC-40",
          "AC-41",
          "AC-42"
        ],
        "code": "AC",
        "description": "42 soft hues inspired by the pale gray of our beautiful coastlines to the rich earth tones of our Southwestern deserts. ",
        "url": "http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/for-your-home/color-gallery?apiKey=9471009bd36bd062c688#&ce_vm=2&ce_col=AC?apiKey=9471009bd36bd062c688",
        "rows": 7,
        "totalColors": 42,
        "eStoreProductCode": null
      },
    ]
  },
  "error": "",
  "countryCode": "en-us",
  "brand": "BenjaminMoore,Corotech,Coronado,Inslx,Lenmar,Maxum"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why PHP json_decode can't parse this JSON

```
 $jsonData = '{
    "data": {
      "name": "Color Collections",
      "category": "collection",
    },
    "error": "",
    "countryCode": "en-us",
    "brand": "BenjaminMoore,Corotech,Coronado,Inslx,Lenmar,Maxum"
  }';
  print_r( json_decode($jsonData, true));
```

> this is my code look and tell me what is happening here? Why PHP can't parse this?

PHP can parse this PHP code fine. And `json_decode` also does the standard operation, lets take a look what this is about.

First the basics on what `json_decode` returns in your example: `NULL`.

Interesting!

Why is this `NULL` return value interesting?

First of all, well obviously on first glance, it is not the JSON text of in the string decoded, or is it?

And second of all, a `NULL` return value from [`json_decode()` is documented](https://www.php.net/json_decode) that it can (but must not) signal an error parsing the JSON text.

Here an excerpt from the PHP manual:

> Return Values
>
> Returns the value encoded in json [reference to the first parameter] in appropriate PHP type. Values `true`, `false` and `null` are returned as `true`, `false` and `null` respectively. **`null` is returned if the json [reference to the first parameter] cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the nesting limit.** [highlight by me]

As the JSON text is not "`null`", seeing `NULL` as the return type signals already there was an issue:

Maybe `json_decode` detected invalid input and refused to operate on it? Or did it hit the nesting limit (the *depth*, the third parameter)? Or was the the string not UTF-8 encoded?

Questions over questions, how to learn more?

In your case you can find it out with [`json_last_error()`](https://php.net/json_last_error)  and [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://php.net/json_last_error_msg) functions. So let's look with the code in question what these functions return: `int(4)` for the error code  and `string(12) "Syntax error"` for the error message.

Oh there is an syntax error in the JSON text passed to `json_decode()`. This means not a nesting limit or character encoding issue!

Let's rephrase:

> Why PHP json_decode can't parse this JSON

Because that JSON has a syntax error.

---

Okay this might now look awkwardly easy right? But wait, what does qualify as JSON  for PHP's `json_decode()`? Well, a look in the manual is mandatory again:

> PHP implements a superset of JSON as specified in the original » [RFC 7159](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc7159.html).

So the (more) correct answer is:

---

Because that JSON text is not in the RFC 7159 JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format.

---

Now that's a statement to impress the boss!

Well now as this answer is out of the way, the next comes: How to deal with it? Well, check the return type and the error functions *or* - recommended nowadays - call json_decode() with the appropriate flags to throw on error:

```
$result = json_decode($jsonData, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

This highlights decoding, character encoding and limit hits etc. directly visible and delegates to the standard error handling procedures so that you can write your code top-down.

---

Well fine, thanks for all the fish, it's all fine and dandy, but still, now I know there is an error but still the *does not work situation* is the same as earlier, so why the snap is that not valid JSON?

If that is still puzzling you or perhaps was the first question right ahead (and not PHP or `json_decode` as written in the question), well then the answer is even simpler: You need to use a tool that tells you *why* that JSON is broken.

This can be syntax highlighting, but more likely you want a validator to show actual errors.

For example within the IDE (here PhpStorm):

1. Mark the content of the string as JSON, e.g. with a PHPDoc:

   ```
   $jsonData = /** @lang JSON */ '{
       "data": {
       ...
   ```
2. Locate any errors within the JSON text string highlighted by the IDE (depending which product you're using this may vary):
   [image]
   here it is wave-underlined in red color
3. Activate the error information of it to obtain more info (for example hover it with the mouse and wait for a tooltip to appear):
   [image]

And again the answer is that the syntax is wrong, here with the hint that

> JSON standard does not allow trailing comma

Now what else is there left to say? If you see an error with json_decode and you can't see the JSON is broken, validate it first. JSON encoding errors are easy to miss just by looking at the JSON text. And often not worth. Invalid JSON? Drop it. And done.

Activate the `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` and your code can merely stay the same, now with batteries included.